# PHP removes everything after & (and) sign

Tags: javascript, php, encoding, parameters

my operations is:

```
var SimTxt = "some text & some other text";
...
xmlhttp.send(&SimTxt ="+SimTxt);
...

<?php 
$SimTxt = $_POST['SimTxt'];

echo

 <button id="btn9" class="sim_btn" type="button">
 '.$simBtn10.'
 </button>
```

But what is printet on screen is only "some text" everything after "&" sign is removed

Comment: Try to pass data as JSON, not STRING. Or you have to use sth like `htmlspecialchars()` in JS on your `SimTxt`.

Comment: First of all it is not being stripped off by PHP. Secondly, you're not using PHP syntax correctly

Comment: [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](http://blog.lunatech.com/2009/02/03/what-every-web-developer-must-know-about-url-encoding) - Guess what a "&" in a URL means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string needs to be encoded before sending :

```
..
var SimTxt = encodeURIComponnent("some text & some other text");
xmlhttp.send(&SimTxt ="+SimTxt);
...
```

-- and the string (which actually is treated as a parameter, and therefore is splitted by `&`), will not be treated as an URI component by PHP.